# Json parsing with autocomplete

Tags: java, android, json, autocompletetextview

I've made an activity that gets jsonarray and puts it in a list. Next i've assigned an AutoCompleteTextView to a field witch fleches the json objects im using.

in my jsonarray its 3 objects: ItemID,ItemDescription and ItemVolume. My AutoCompleteTextView field contains jsonObject: ItemDescription.

I need to get the itemID when the itemDescription is selected in my onItemClickListner.

Heres the code

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(shoppingcart.this,
        android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, responseList);
autocomplete.setAdapter(adp);
autocomplete.setThreshold(1);

private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(shoppingcart.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        // Getting JSON from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(urlget);
        return json;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        autocomplete.setThreshold(1);
        try {

            // Getting JSON Array from URL
            AllItems = json.getJSONArray(TAG_GETALL);
            for(int i = 0; i < AllItems.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = AllItems.getJSONObject(i);

                // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
                ID = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                Name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                Pris = c.getString(TAG_PRICE);

                // Adding value HashMap key => value

                responseList.add(Name);

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

This is what i did for the List parts.

```
HashMap<String,Integer> ItemAndID= new HashMap<String,Integer>();
List<String> responseList = new ArrayList<String>();
 @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
            pDialog.dismiss();

            try {
                 AllItems = json.getJSONArray(TAG_GETALL);
                for(int i = 0; i < AllItems.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = AllItems.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
                    ID = c.getInt(TAG_ID);
                    Name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    Pris = c.getInt(TAG_PRICE);

                    // Adding value HashMap key => value

                    responseList.add(Name);


                    ItemAndID.put(Name, ID);


                }
```

For OnClick I did this.

```
  @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String selectedName = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            // if you used a HashMap
            ResultID = ItemAndID.get(selectedName);



        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See this example](http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-autocompletetextview-example-json/) you are not saving ItemId anywhere. If you don't want to create a new Object, you can create a new list to save ItemIds or you can create a `HaspMap<String, String>` like ["name1":"id1","name2":"id2"] and then depending on what you use to save ItemId

```
setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {              
        String selectedName = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        // if you used a HashMap
        String ID = exampleHashMap.get(selectedName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer, see my post for result.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new list like responseListItemId and pares it along side responseList:

```
List<Integer> responseListItemId = new ArrayList<Integer>();
.....
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {

    JSONObject c = AllItems.getJSONObject(i);

    // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
    ID = c.getString(TAG_ID);
    Name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
    Pris = c.getString(TAG_PRICE);

    // Adding value HashMap key => value

    responseList.add(Name);
    responseListItemId.add(ID);

}
```

Now get the index value of the description from the **responseList** and use it in the **responseListItemId** to get your itemID.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to create a custom class for your data type like Product and ten create a custom adapter see https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView